# How can I create users in SugarCRM using SOAP?

Tags: php, soap, sugarcrm

I want to bind SugarCRM to an existing ERP tool. Users are to be managed (added and deleted) in the ERP tool so I need to be able to add users via SOAP.

So far I have not found a means to create a user account in SugarCRM in a way that a system generated password is in turn mailed to the user's address.

Any pointers where to look in the code? I'd hate to fill all data into $_POST and then call Users/Save.php...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently it's not possible but you could make your own Web Service method by extending SugarCRM Web Service by upgrade safe way : http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.1/02_Application_Framework#Extensibility_in_Upgrade_Safe_Manner

This method could be based on code available in modules/Users/GeneratePassword.php and you could call this methode after a "set_entry" call to send password to your new user.

Comment: I know about the SOAP versioning but the pointer to GeneratePassword.php (and the there included calls to User::generatePassword() and $user->sendEmailForPassword()) served my needs quite well. Thanks!